# the volume of pyramid value

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, determinant

when calculating the volume of pyramid using a determinnat, is it ok to take the determinanat in absloute value so that every negative result would be converted to positive volume number?

Comment: Yes it depends on order. Even for plane area two signs arise in determinant evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

Since area must always be positive, it would be advised to use absolute values to convert negative values to positive values.